# Why doesn't getline(cin, var) after cin.ignore() read the first character of the string?

Tags: c++, input, cin, getline

I'm creating a simple console application in C++ that gets string and char inputs from the user. To make things simple, I would like to use the **string** and **char** data types to pass input from cin to.

To get string inputs, I'm using the **getline** method:

```
string var;
cin.ignore(); //I used ignore() because it prevents skipping a line after using cin >> var
getline(cin, var);
```

To get char inputs, I'm using the **cin >> var** method:

```
char var;
cin >> var;
```

This works fine for the most part. However, when I enter a string using **getline**, it ignores the first character of my string.

Is it possible to use **getline** and **cin >>** without having to use **ignore**, or a method I can call to ensure that my first character isn't skipped?

This is a full sample of code where I use both **getline** and **cin >>**:

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
char gender = 'A';

cout << "First Name: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, firstName);


cout << "Last Name: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, lastName);

while(genderChar != 'M' && genderChar != 'F')
{
    cout << "Gender (M/F): ";
    cin >> genderChar;
    genderChar = toupper(genderChar);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comments for cin.ignore(). Based on its api definition, it will discard the first character of string you input, just as the scenario you encounter now.

Comment: @JinChen sorry, fixed. I meant to say that if I DON'T use ignore(), it skips a line of input.

Comment: still weird, cin.ignore() should not behavior like that. Can you provide more code of your problem?

Comment: @JinChen updated again with some sample code. The comments are where my problems are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cin>>var;`

only grabs the `var` from the buffer, it leaves the `\n` in the buffer,
which is then immediately grabbed up by the `getline`

So, following is just fine, (if I understood correctly your problem)

```
cin>>var;
cin.ignore();     //Skip trailing '\n'
getline(cin, var);
```

As per your **edited** post

You don't have to use `cin.ignore();` for `geline`

This extracts characters from buffer and stores them into `firstName` or (`lastName`) until the delimitation character here -newline (`'\n'`).

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin.ignore()` will ignore the first character of your input.

For your case, use `std::cin.ignore()` after `std::cin` and then `getline()` to ignore newline character as:

```
cin>>ch;
cin.ignore();  //to skip the newline character in the buffer
getline(cin,var);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ignore()` does not skip a line, it skips a character. Could you send example code and elaborate on the need for `cin.ignore()`?

Comment: I updated the question with some sample code :) but I think my question became a bit unclear in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `std::isstream::ignore()` before `std::getline()`. `std::cin.ignore()` will extract the first character from the input sequence and discard that.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

Answer (score 0):

So basically, `cin>>var`  leaves the '\n' character out of its buffer. So now when you call
getline it reads the '\n' character and stops. Therefore we use cin.ignore() to ignore the first character getline reads i.e '\n' when we use it after cin.

But getline doesn't leave '\n' character instead it stores everything in its buffer till it find '\n' character, then stores '\n' character as well and then stops.

So in your code when you are using cin.ignore() after a getline and again uses getline to take input, it ignores the first character of the string instead of '\n'.
That is why the first character is missing.

Hope this answers your question.