# Code is failing to run properly after trying to read input from file

Tags: c++

I have an input file set up like this:

```
Hello there
1 4
Goodbye now
4.9 3
```

And I try to read the data as so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream input("file.txt");
    string name;
    double num1, num2;

    while(!input.eof()){
        getline(input, name);
        input >> num1;
        input >> num2;

        cout << name << endl;
        cout << num1 << " " << num2 << endl;
    }
}
```

But the read seems to be failing. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: `getline` didn't remove the `\n` from the stream

Comment: Prefer `"\n"` to `std::endl` unless you have a reason to flush.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: `getline` with `>>`.  Solution from this post: [C++ iostream: Using cin >> var and getline(cin, var) input errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348350/c-iostream-using-cin-var-and-getlinecin-var-input-errors)

Problem 2: `inupt.eof()` to test the end of loop, this post: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  ifstream input("dat.txt");
  string name;
  double num1, num2;

  while (getline(input, name)) {  // getline fails at the end of file
    input >> num1 >> num2;
    input.ignore();
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: The output i get with your code for the file contents mentioned in the question is 

Hello there \n
1 4 \n
0 4

Comment: @AbhishekBagchi Interesting, I got the correct output with `gcc 4.8` on `Ubuntu 13.10`.

Answer (score 0):

This would work..

```
ifstream input("command2");
string name;
double num1, num2;

int x;

while(getline(input, name)){
    input >> num1;
    input >> num2;
    input.clear();
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << endl;
    string dummy;
    getline(input,dummy);
}
```

I write the second getline() to make sure that the \n at the line with 1 4 is read.

Without that, what i get is

```
Hello there
1 4

0 4
Goodbye now
4.9 3
```

Hope this helps.