# C++ weird cin.ignore behaviour

Tags: c++

i'm trying to build a sample app for my students which should demonstrate how to enter multiple c-strings using cin.getline and cin.ignore but i'm getting weird results. in my code below there are two commented cin.ignore statements. if i uncomment first one then in runtime it is required to press Enter twice to input the first string and only once to input the second. if i uncomment second one instead then both strings inputted with one Enter but second string somehow lose first letter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Unit{
    int uid;
    char* name=new char[50];
    char* shname=new char[10];
};

int main() {
    Unit u;
    cout << "Record number: ";
    cin >> u.uid;
    cout << "Unit name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(u.name,50);
    //cin.ignore();
    cout << "Unit short name: ";
    //cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(u.shname,10);
    cout << "Record number: " << u.uid << endl
         << "Unit name: " << u.name << endl
         << "Unit short name: " << u.shname << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i cant quite understand what am i doing wrong

Comment: "what am i doing wrong" using `new` and C style strings, for starters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ iostream: Using cin >> var and getline(cin, var) input errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348350/c-iostream-using-cin-var-and-getlinecin-var-input-errors)

Comment: `getline()` reads up to and including the newline, so there should be no need to `ignore()`. What happens when both are commented out?

Answer (score 1):

`cin.ignore()` ignores only one character, no matter if it is white space or not.

I guess you want to ignore until the first non-white character.

For example:

```
while (iswspace(cin.peek()))
   cin.ignore();
```

And as said in the comment, `getline` will read also the end of line. you need to ignore it after use the stream operator (`>>`) because then it stop before the end of line and the first `getline` will read just the new line.

Comment: `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: @n.m it depends, do you want to ignore valid input till the new line, or take the input in the current line. what about spaces before the value? do you want to start from the spaces or in the beginning of not-white characters? and what about lines longer than size? there is no single answer for all cases.

Comment: ok, i get it. i don't need to use ignore if i'm reading several strings using getline. i need to use it only if i mix >> and getline calls. thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to understand *why* it is sometimes necessary to use `ignore()`! The built-in  formatted input pperations (`operator>>()`) use any space chararcter as a separator which is **not** extracted. On the other hand, `getline()` scans the input for the first occurance of the newline character (by default `’\n’`) and stores and stores and extracts all those characters. It finishes with extracting the newline character (the variation you are using also has a size constraint; I’d recomend using `std::string` with the non-memeber `std::getline()`).

The net effect is that after a formatted input function the next character in the buffer is a separating space. When intaracting with a user using the standard input it is most likely a newline character which causes a following `getline()` to immediately finish. Thus, it is common that these space characters are extract, preferably using `in >> std::ws` rather than `in.ignore()` to deal with other stray space characters. After using `getline()` there is generally no need to skip any characters as the newline is already extracted. Put differently: the commented `ignore()`s are best removed.

Also, make sure you **always** verify the input was successful **after** trying to read! The vaste majority of errors with inout are due to no checking (as is the case in the code you posted) or checking *before* the input operations. Learning to check afterwards is sufficiently important that the argument of “making the code simple” doesn’t hold: it isn’t making the code simple but plain wrong!